# TimeoutException: WebViewClassic.finalize() timed out after 10 seconds

Tags: java, android, webview, timeoutexception

I use an Android WebView, which is dynamically added and removed based on timers. I have noticed a few crashes caused by the following exception.

```
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: android.webkit.WebViewClassic.finalize() timed out after 10 seconds
    at android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueMessage(MessageQueue.java:318)
    at android.os.Handler.enqueueMessage(Handler.java:626)
    at android.os.Handler.sendMessageAtFrontOfQueue(Handler.java:618)
    at android.webkit.WebViewCore$EventHub.sendMessageAtFrontOfQueue(WebViewCore.java:1873)
    at android.webkit.WebViewCore$EventHub.access$7200(WebViewCore.java:1063)
    at android.webkit.WebViewCore.destroy(WebViewCore.java:1987)
    at android.webkit.WebViewClassic.destroyJava(WebViewClassic.java:2208)
    at android.webkit.WebViewClassic.destroy(WebViewClassic.java:2183)
    at android.webkit.WebViewClassic.finalize(WebViewClassic.java:4266)
    at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:187)
    at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:170)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

I cannot find the root of this problem. I tried disabling hardware acceleration, which did not work.

```
view.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

My code for creating the WebView looks like this.

```
public static void setupWebView(WebView view, String url) {
     view.loadUrl(url);

     view.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null); // Did not fix TimeoutException

     view.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
     view.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
     view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
     view.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
     view.getSettings().setSaveFormData(false);

     // Make the web view handle links on visited pages
     view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
         @Override
         public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
             view.loadUrl(url);
             return true;
         }
     });
 }
```

I remove the view just by calling `parent.removeView(webView)` on the parent view.

Any ideas that could lead me solving this problem?

The system runs on Android devices >= 4.2.2.

Comment: also encountered this problem, did you find a solution to this?

Comment: No, I never found a solution. However, I haven't gotten this error lately so it might have been fixed by other changes I have done since I asked the question. I did, for instance, try to fix a few memory leaks using https://github.com/square/leakcanary.